# C++ quick issue on getline(cin, string)

Tags: c++, string

Its been a while since i have coded c++ and i have forgot an annoying thing that happens when you gather string input.  Basically if this loops back through, say if you use negative numbers then it skips the cin from the employee name line the second go round.  I remember having this issue before and having to clear or do something of that sort before or after the string is input.  Please help!

PS Also for extra help can anyone help me with a correct loop below.  How can i check for a value in the string input to make sure they input a value?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string name;
    int number;
    int hiredate;

    do{

        cout << "Please enter employee name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Please enter employee number: ";
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Please enter hire date: ";
        cin >> hiredate;

    }while( number <= 0 && hiredate <= 0 && name != "");

    cout << name << "\n";
    cout << number << "\n";
    cout << hiredate << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only want the loop to stop when the name is `""`? I think you want `name == ""`?  I think you also want to use or (`||`) rather than and (`&&`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change your loop condition to be whether or not any of the below are not set.  The logical AND will only trigger if all *three* are unset.

```
do {
    ...
} while( number <= 0 || hiredate <= 0 || name == "");
```

Next, use `cin.ignore()` as prescribed by @vidit to get rid of issues with reading in newline characters.

Lastly, and importantly, your program **will run an infinite loop** if one enters an alphabetic character for an integer instead of...an integer.  To mitigate that, use `isdigit(ch)` from the `<cctype>` library.

```
 cout << "Please enter employee number: ";
 cin >> number;
 if(!isdigit(number)) {
    break; // Or handle this issue another way.  This gets out of the loop entirely.
 }
 cin.ignore();
```

Answer (score 1):

`cin` leaves a newline character(`\n`) in the stream, which causes the next cin to consume it. There are many ways of getting around that. This is one way.. using `ignore()`

```
cout << "Please enter employee name: ";
getline(cin, name);
cout << "Please enter employee number: ";
cin >> number;
cin.ignore();           //Ignores a newline character
cout << "Please enter hire date: ";
cin >> hiredate;
cin.ignore()            //Ignores a newline character
```

Comment: Good, but it doesn't fix the issue if you enter a character instead of an integer for number, nor does it resolve the loop if you enter nothing for a name.